# vbs deletefile method not working when script called from batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, delete-file

I've created a vbs file that renames files in a folder.  However if the file to be renamed already exists it deletes the file before renaming it.

My script works fine if I run it directly from windows explorer but if I run the script from a batch file or from Task Scheduler the deletefile method does not execute.  The renaming part still works.

The script is:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' folder containing files to be renamed
strFolder="\\FullNetworkFilePath\rename"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    ' Look at pdf files only
    If LCase(objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile)) = "pdf" Then    
        strFileName = strFile.Name
       ' Look for files prefixed with ODP
       If InStr(strFileName,"ODP") > 0 Then   
           ' substitute ODP with Ope in the file name        
           strNewFileName = Replace(strFileName,"ODP","Ope")

           If objFS.fileexists(strNewFileName) Then
               ' if the Ope version of the file already exists, delete the ODP version of the file
               ' MsgBox strNewFileName & " already exists. " & strFilename & " will be deleted."
               objFS.deletefile(strFilename)
           Else
               ' if the Ope version of the file does not exist, rename the ODP version of the file
               ' MsgBox strNewFileName & " does not exist. " & strFilename & " will be renamed."
               strFile.Name = strNewFileName
           End If

        End If 
    End If  
Next
```

The batch file scripts I have tried are:

```
cscript "\\FullNetworkFilePath\rename\rename.vbs"
```

and

```
c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe "\\FullNetworkFilePath\rename\rename.vbs"
```

The task scheduler runs the vbs script with highest priviledges ticked.

Does anyone know why the deletefile method does not work when the vbs is called from a batch file or from task scheduler (but the name method does)?  Ultimately I need it to work from Task Scheduler.

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next`, run it and see what the error is

Comment: Thanks FloatingKiwi.  I did some bug checking and figured out that the .fileexists and .deletefile methods needed the full file path passed to them, not just the file name.  I guess when the script was just run in isolation within the same folder it didn't need the file path.  But once you get cscript or Task Manager to execute the script, they would have been looking for the files in the folder which they run from.

Comment: Do you have sufficient privileges for deletion on the files?